# Control external monitor brightness via software

Tags: brightness, external-monitor

Hello Ubuntu community,

I can control the brightness of my DELL U2713HM connected with DisplayPort via the command:

```
ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w 53
```

where in this example the number 53 represents the brightness level (range 0 to 100). But I don't know how to link the command to my brightness keys on  my keyboard.

I searched already, but just found answers to integrated laptop screens. In `/sys/class/backlight` is the folder `acpi_video0` with some subfolders and files. The file actual_brightness contains a number from 0 to 20, which is changing when I press the brightness keys.

**How do I get my external monitor listed as a device in /sys/class/backlight ?**

PS: I am running a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 install with integrated graphics Intel HD4000.

Comment: When the command you provided works for your external monitor you can set custom shortcut keys in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: That is correct, but then I can just send two commands (dark/bright) and I would ignore the Ubuntu internal brightness changer with the nice brightness animation.

Comment: Can you post a link with the output of `ddccontrol -p`, I'm thinking of a solution...

Comment: Hope this is any help for you: http://pastebin.com/L7Y7pRZe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your desired solution of getting your external monitor in `/sys/class/backlight` will work, but the good news is that you can have the nice brightness animation!

Try

```
notify-send " " -i notification-display-brightness-low -h int:value:50 -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:brightness &
```

Now we can make a script that simulates Ubuntu's brightness changer:

```
#!/bin/bash
#get current brightness
presbright=$(ddccontrol -p | grep -A1 0x10 | tr -d '\n\t' | sed 's/.*value=\([^a-zA-Z]*\),.*/\1/')
#stepsize for the brightness change
stepsize=10

case "$1" in
        up)
          newbright=$(( ${presbright}+${stepsize} ))
          newbright=$(echo $newbright | awk '{if($1 < 100){if($1 > 0) print $1; else print 0;} else print 100;}')

          notify-send " " -i notification-display-brightness-low -h int:value:$newbright -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:brightness &
          ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w $newbright
        ;;
        down)
          newbright=$(( ${presbright}-${stepsize} ))
          newbright=$(echo $newbright | awk '{if($1 < 100){if($1 > 0) print $1; else print 0;} else print 100;}')

          notify-send " " -i notification-display-brightness-low -h int:value:$newbright -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:brightness &
          ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w $newbright            
        ;;
        status)
          echo $presbright
        ;;
        *)
          echo "Accepted arguments are: up, down, status."
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

As you can see it clamps the values between 0 and 100. Now you can bind the `up` and `down` calls to the script to some keyboard shortcuts of your choice with **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**, like fotomonster suggested.

---

**Notes:**
I don't know how much time `ddccontrol -p` takes, if it is too long you can also add a `sync` option to the script which saves the brightness value of the monitor to a file. Then instead of getting the current brightness from `ddccontrol` you can simply get it from your file, which should be much faster. Of course you would need to update the `up` and `down` calls to write the new brightness to the file...

---

script inspired by [this post on archlinux](https://alderaan.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=981260).

Comment: works very well, thank you very much. That is exactly what I wanted. Now the whole system is well integrated, like an iMac, but still configurable.

Comment: Still need a little help, binding the script to my brightness keys: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239560/problem-binding-a-shortcut-to-multimedia-key