# Problem binding a shortcut to a function / multimedia key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

I want to connect a batch script to a shortcut. When I bind it under **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts** it works with every key, except my brightness keys from my external Apple keyboard.

The brightness keys are recognized in showkey with the keycode **224** and **225**.

xev output:

```
FocusOut event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any suggestions what I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution using halevt

According to the man pages `halevt` is a generic handler for HAL events. It is deprecated and replaced by `udev`, but since I don't know enough about `udev` I will give a `halevt` solution.

**EDIT:** after some serious sweat, I managed to do this in `udev`. See [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/240879/41499).

I will use `vim` to edit files, but if you don't know `vim` you can replace it by `nano` or `gedit`.

**Installing halevt**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install halevt
```

**Determining which events you want to bind to a script**
Stop the `halevt` daemon which is already running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/halevt stop
```

Now see if `halevt` can recognize the events of the keys you want to use, start the listener:

```
sudo -u halevt halevt -fig:plugdev
```

Now press the function key on your keyboard you want to bind the script to. I know that the OP wants to get his brightness keys working, so let's go with that. The output for the brightness keys should look something like this:

```
Condition: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_KBD_port_logicaldev_input,ButtonPressed (brightness-down)
Condition: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_i8042_i8042_KBD_port_logicaldev_input,ButtonPressed (brightness-up)
```

You can see that the `brightness-down` and `brightness-up` events are transmitted.

**Bind the event to a script**
Now edit the file `/etc/halevt/halevt.xml`:

```
sudo vim /etc/halevt/halevt.xml
```

and add the following lines ( I did it at the bottom, just before `</halevt:Configuration>`):

```
<halevt:Device match="hal.info.category = input">

    <halevt:Condition name="ButtonPressed" value="brightness-up" exec="sudo /home/user/brightness-script.sh up"/>

    <halevt:Condition name="ButtonPressed" value="brightness-down" exec="sudo /home/user/brightness-script.sh down"/>

</halevt:Device>
```

where of course you should change `value` to the event that you got from the listener, and `exec` by the command you want to execute.

**Give the halevt user permission to do the command or script**
Since the `halevt` daemon is run as the `halevt` user you have to give it permission to do what you specified in `exec`.

Run (remember to replace `vim` by your editor of choice)

```
sudo EDITOR=vim visudo
```

and add the following lines at the bottom

```
halevt ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/brightness-script.sh
```

and save and quit.

**Make sure your script is executable**

```
sudo chmod +x /home/user/brightness-script.sh
```

**Start the halevt daemon again**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/halevt start
```

**And it should be working!**

Comment: worked flawlessly. thank you again for your precise answer.

Comment: You're welcome, see also [my new answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/240879/41499) using `udev`. But feel free to stick with the other solution, the important thing is that it's working ;)

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package halevt` on 14.04.

Comment: Since Ubuntu 13.10 halevt is no longer included ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=halevt)

Answer (score 11):

### Solution using udev

Since HAL is deprecated and `udev` is now used, this approach is preferred over [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/240452/41499) (although I think that the solution using HAL is simpler).

However for many function keys you can simply use *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts* to bind a script, try this first! It saves you a lot of trouble.
For for instance the brightness keys this doesn't work (I don't have a clue why not), so if you want to know how to change the behavior of for example the brightness keys, read on.

**NOTE**: If you are running a Samsung notebook you can fix all (depending on model) function keys by installing the `samsung-tools` package from http://www.voria.org/forum/

This howto assumes you know how to use a terminal, and uses the `vim` editor. If you don't know `vim` please replace it in the commands by either `gedit` or `nano`.

---

**Determining your keyboard**

```
/lib/udev/findkeyboards
```

should print the keyboards that are connected to the computer, in my case

```
USB keyboard: input/event9
USB keyboard: input/event7
AT keyboard: input/event4
```

Now there are two options:

- *USB keyboards*:
  If you want to remap your USB keyboard, inspect them by running

  ```
  udevadm info --export-db | awk '/event9/' RS="" | grep -P 'ID_(VENDOR|MODEL)(?!_ENC)'
  ```

  where you have to replace the 9 in the awk statement by the correct number. The output should be similar to

  ```
  E: ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
  E: ID_MODEL_ID=c52b
  E: ID_VENDOR=Logitech
  E: ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
  ```

  which correctly indicates that my keyboard is handled via my Logitech USB Receiver (input/event7 turned out to be my Logitech G9 mouse which has some programmable buttons).
- *Laptop Keyboard* :
  If you want to remap your laptop keyboard, you should remember the number for the `AT keyboard` which is 4 in my case. Also get the dmi information  for your laptop:

  ```
  cat /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor
  ```

  which is in my case

  ```
  SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
  ```

  and

  ```
  cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
  ```

  which is in my case

  ```
  305U1A
  ```

---

**Determine your current mapping of your function keys**

Now we can determine our current keymapping by listening to the keyboard (insert correct number)

```
sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event4
```

you can exit this command by using <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the keyboard, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on another keyboard.

If your screen starts scrolling down very hard, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> a few times and try again with

```
sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event4 2> /dev/null
```

or, if you still have the scrolling issue

```
sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event4 > ~/keymap.log
```

In the last case you will still have the scrolling but if you press the functions keys they should go into `~/keymap.log` where you can read them later.

Now we can check the current mapping of your Function keys by pressing them, which should give you a list like (this is my <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>):

```
scan code: 0xCE   key code: kpplusminus
scan code: 0x89   key code: brightnessdown
scan code: 0x88   key code: brightnessup
scan code: 0x82   key code: switchvideomode
scan code: 0xF9   key code: f23
scan code: 0xA0   key code: mute
scan code: 0xAE   key code: volumedown
scan code: 0xB0   key code: volumeup
scan code: 0x43   key code: f9
scan code: 0x44   key code: f10
scan code: 0xB3   key code: prog3
scan code: 0x86   key code: wlan
```

Now write down the scan codes for which you want the behavior to change.

---

**Changing the key codes for the scan codes**

If you see the key code clearly doesn't cover what you expect the key to do you can have a look in `/usr/include/linux/input.h` under *Keys and buttons* to see if there is a key code that better matches  what you actually want to happen. The key codes there are in the format `KEY_KEYCODE` and you have have to write down the part after `KEY_` in lowercase. Sometimes changing this is enough to solve the problem.

The brightness keys however often have the right keycode associated with them, and this is what doesn't allow them to be remapped. So we need to change them to other keycodes. We will use `prog1` and `prog2` for this example because these aren't in use on my computer, however you can also use `f13` through `f24`, or `f20` through `f24` if you have an Apple keyboard which has <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F19</kbd> keys.

1. *Create a custom keymap*:
   Create a keymap file in the directory `/lib/udev/keymaps` with a suitable name, have a look at the output of `ls /lib/udev/keymaps` to see for suitable names. I am going with `custom-brightness` for the purpose of this question.

   ```
   sudo vim /lib/udev/keymaps/custom-brightness
   ```

   and enter the scan codes of the keys you want to change followed by the scancodes you want them to have. My `custom-brightness` looks like this:

   ```
   # /lib/udev/keymaps/custom-brightness

   0x89 prog1
   0x88 prog2
   ```
2. *Create a custom key release file.* **Only if you are changin your laptop keyboard**:
   Sometimes the key release event is not properly send, causing the computer to hang. To avoid this we will also write a custom key release file

   ```
   sudo vim /lib/udev/keymaps/force-release/custom-brightness
   ```

   this file should contain the same scan codes, mine looks like

   ```
   # /lib/udev/keymaps/force-release/custom-brightness

   0x89
   0x88
   ```

---

**Make sure that the new mappings are loaded in the rules files**
Now we need to make sure that your mappings are loaded. We can do this by editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules`, so it is smart to make a backup

Again we have two options:

- *USB keyboards*:
  Since you have a USB keyboard you should add your entry under `LABEL="keyboard_usbcheck"` and it should be past the other entries of your keyboard manufacturer. This is because my keyboard with

  ```
  E: ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
  E: ID_MODEL_ID=c52b
  E: ID_VENDOR=Logitech
  E: ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
  ```

  is already matched by one of the rules, and otherwise it gets overwritten.
  Add the following rule, where you should change the `ID_VENDOR_ID` and `ID_MODEL_ID` and the name of your keymap appropiately

  ```
  ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="046d", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="c52b", RUN+="keymap $name custom-brightness"
  ```
- *Laptop keyboard*:
  If `/lib/udev/findkeyboards` reported your laptop keyboard as `AT keyboard` your rule should go under `LABEL="keyboard_vendorcheck"`, otherwise put it under `LABEL="keyboard_modulecheck"`. Again put it under the other entries for your laptop manufactorer. Add the following rule (`SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.` is bit long so I used a wildcard`)

  ```
  ENV{DMI_VENDOR}=="SAMSUNG*", ATTR{[dmi/id]product_name}=="305U1A", RUN+="keymap $name custom_brightness"
  ```

  Now also add a rule to `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules` after backing it up

  ```
  sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules.bak
  sudo vim /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules
  ```

  Again under the other entries of your manufacturer add

  ```
  ENV{DMI_VENDOR}=="SAMSUNG*", ATTR{[dmi/id]product_name}=="305U1A", RUN+="keyboard-force-release.sh $devpath custom_test"
  ```

---

**Make sure udev loads the new rules**
To load the new rules run

```
sudo adevadm trigger
```

NOTE: `udevadm control --reload-rules` (still in instructions on many websites) does not work.

Now check if the rules were applied successfully by

```
sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event4
```

which should now report for the brightness keys

```
scan code: 0x89   key code: prog1
scan code: 0x88   key code: prog2
```

---

**Remap the keys in System Settings**
If the last step reported the correct key codes, either the keys start automatically working (in case they first had the wrong key codes).

For the brightness you still have to bind the keys to a scrip which is now possible using *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*.

**Enjoy**

---

---

**Notes**:

- If your keys had the wrong key code and were fixed by this approach, please follow the instructions in `/usr/share/doc/udev/README.keymap.txt.gz` (you can open this without extracting using `zless`) and send your results the email adres mentioned there, then the changes can be included in the next release. Many users will benefit!
- Many thanks to [this](http://jablonskis.org/2012/linux-and-samsung-series-laptop-9-fn-keys/) helpful post by Vaidas Jablonskis.

Comment: `$ /lib/udev/findkeyboards
bash: /lib/udev/findkeyboards: No such file or directory` also `$ /lib/udev/findkeyboards
bash: /lib/udev/findkeyboards: No such file or directory`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I looked into it and it appears udev will be merged into systemd and keymap settings will be  managed in hwdb instead. According to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168720 it is possible to extract findkeyboards from an older version of systemd, but I'm unsure the rest of the answer still applies...