# Control monitor brightness with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, brightness

I can control the brightness of my DELL S2216H connected with HDMI via the command:

```
ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w 53
```

where in this example the number 53 represents the brightness level (range 0 to 100). But I don't know how to link the command to my brightness keys on my keyboard or add laptop like slider next to volume control in Gnome-panel

while searching on the topic, i read this question
[Control external monitor brightness via software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220886/control-external-monitor-brightness-via-software)
but the accepted answer to that question doesn't solve my issue

my output of `ddccontrol -p` is is [posted here at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GfuvkH9k)

**UPDATE**
tried the first solution.

```
python3 /home/sumeet/set_brightness.py up

No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.
If your graphics card need it, please check all the required kernel modules are loaded (i2c-dev, and your framebuffer driver).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumeet/set_brightness.py", line 22, in <module>
    currval = int(next(obj for obj in section if obj.startswith("value")).split("=")[-1].strip(","))
StopIteration
```

**UPDATE 2**

output of [This Script](https://pastebin.com/tTA9qM3Q) from what I understand it's not even detecting my monitor. but first (original) command still works

```
python3 /home/sumeet/brightness.py
No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.
If your graphics card need it, please check all the required kernel modules are loaded (i2c-dev, and your framebuffer driver).
ddccontrol version 0.4.2
Copyright 2004-2005 Oleg I. Vdovikin (oleg@cs.msu.su)
Copyright 2004-2006 Nicolas Boichat (nicolas@boichat.ch)
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

Probing for available monitors.......
Detected monitors :
```

**UPDATE 3**
even the first command isn't working now, how can i get that working?

[image: Brightness Slider in laptops]

Comment: I don't have ddcontrol, but if you can give me the command to set the brightness to a specific value, I can provide you the commands to run from a shortcut.

Comment: `ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w 53` this command can be used to set brightness at 53 percent, last digit in the command indicates value ranging from 0 to 100. i'll need two commands one for adding +5 value in the existing brightness value and 2nd for deducing i.e, -5 value in the existing brightness value

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GfuvkH9k this might also help you

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm that'd be great

Comment: Don't worry, we'll get it done one way or another :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I believe you, cause almost all of my problems got solved because of ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56538/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-sumeet-deshmukh).

Comment: Fwiw, `xbacklight` can also adjust brightness from command line.

Comment: @wjandrea that's not working either

Answer (score 2):

## Bind a keyboard shortcut

Gnome allows you to bind any key to run a command of your choice. If `xbacklight` worked, I'd suggest you use that. Since you said it does not, you can use the `brightness` script I'll include below.

1. Go to Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts and scroll to the bottom of the list.
2. You'll find a <kbd>+</kbd> button. Click it to open the Add Custom Shortcut dialog: [image: Add Custom Shortcut]

   1. For the Name put "Brightness Up", for the Command, type `brightness +10`
   2. Click the "Set Shortcut" button and hit the key you want to turn the screen brighter.
3. Now do the same for "Brightness Down", using `brightness -10`. [image: Add shortcut]

### b9's brightness script

Many external monitors cannot control the backlight lamp with `xbacklight`. But you can still control the brightness using software. Here's a script I wrote which does that.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# brightness: Change all monitors brightness in software.
# by hackerb9, 2019

# Examples:  brightness 75;  brightness -5; brightness +10
# Usage:
#       brightess [n] [+n] [-n]
#       n       An integer from 0 to 100 specifies a brightness level.
#       +n      Increase brightness by n.
#       -n      Decrease brightness by n.
#               No argument shows current brightness level.

b=$(xrandr --current --verbose | grep Brightness)
b=${b#*: }                      # Remove "Brightness: "
b=${b#0.}                       # 0.30 --> 30
[[ $b == "1.0" ]] && b="100"
case $1 in
    +*|-*)
        b=$((b $1))             # b=b+10,  b=b-10
        ;;
    [0-9]*)
        b=$1                    # b=75
        ;;
    *)
        echo $b; exit
        ;;
esac

[[ $b -lt 0 ]] && b=0
[[ $b -gt 100 ]] && b=100

if [[ $b -eq 100 ]]; then
    b=1.0
else
    b=0.$b
fi

outputs=$(xrandr --current | awk '$2 == "connected" {print $1}')
for o in $outputs; do
    xrandr --output $o --brightness $b
done
```

To install the script, paste it into a file called `brightness`, set it executable, and put it in your path. Or, you can cut-and-paste these commands:

1. wget https://github.com/hackerb9/brightness/raw/master/brightness
2. chmod 755 brightness
3. sudo mv brightness /usr/local/bin/

### xbacklight

If `xbacklight` did work for you, you could use it as a drop-in replacement for `brightness` in the above instructions. (`xbacklight +10` for Brightness Up, `xbacklight -10` for Down.)

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much for this answer! This is exactly what I needed. (Unfortunately I have already bricked my monitor with ddccontrol at the point of writing this comment, but still! good to know!)