# Brightness Adjustment on Desktop Computer

Tags: screen, brightness, effects

I have Ubuntu 12.10

I need an application/software that can increase and decrease my brightness.

I know I can do it through my pc monitor but I don't want that. I want to control it through a software.

I personally cannot find an application about this issue.

I know that it is possible because the OS has the Fading effects before Screen Savers.

> I want to control brightness through a software for desktop pc.

Comment: Brightness is in most cases hardware-controlled with the lamps in the screen. In a Desktop, i am unsure if that is possible with older screens. Could i have the details about your screen?

Comment: The fading effect is just a darker image send to your monitor. The actual backlight of your monitor does not change. But there is still software, that can send a command to your monitor to lower its backlight (ddccontrol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the controls on your monitor, you can do it via your driver applet in case you are using proprietary drivers from nvidia or ati or you can use xbacklight from the software center.

Comment: and is there any widget for it so that I can do it from my desktop?

Comment: @DjBmNukez Yes there is, see my answer.

Answer (score 21):

Install [Brightness Controller](http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness) from its PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Picture: Brightness Controller

Now you can adjust the brightness using the slider.

**Note**: You will have to disable redshift/night light for the program to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me on ubuntu 14.04.  Had to start this app from terminal like:  `$ brightness-controller`

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl You can start the app from dash in Unity

Comment: That's a beautiful solution!

Comment: Worth noting this tool uses `xrandr` to control color levels via software. A proper tool would use DDC protocol to interact directly with the display, allowing the same kind of control as the built-in menu in the display itself.

Comment: This program has a bug, brightness increases automatically after a while.

Comment: @hafiz031 You will have to disable redshift/nightlight. They interfere. This is not a bug of the program.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no this still happens when night light is disabled. I experience this specially when I encounter some video running on Facebook or LinkedIn.

Comment: @hafiz031 I never experiences the issue you described. You can open an issue at GitHub. https://github.com/lordamit/brightness/

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi here you go: https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/issues/193#issue-930647111

Comment: Works beautifully on pop-os 21.10. Thank you for suggesting this.

Answer (score 12):

Use DDC protocol:

```
sudo apt-get install ddccontrol
sudo modprobe i2c-dev

sudo ddccontrol -p
```

Note the device e.g "/dev/i2c-2"

Set the permissions (if needed):

```
sudo chmod a=+rw /dev/i2c-2
```

Under "Brightness and Contrast", the control address is "0x10" in my case.

```
ddccontrol dev:/dev/i2c-2 -r 0x10 -w 70
```

70 is the brightness value to set.

If you only want to query:

```
ddccontrol dev:/dev/i2c-2 -r 0x10
```

You can play with contrast and other parameters as well; note their addresses in the

```
ddccontrol -p
```

command.

Answer (score 1):

the brightness can be adjusted via the [DDC/IC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel). The software is called `ddccontrol` and can be found [here](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/). For an example see my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218993/how-to-change-external-monitor-brightness-via-ddc-ic/219967#219967).

I can control my monitor (brightness, contrast, standby, ...) with the software. But I can just send absolute brightness values to the monitor. I would like to in-/decrease the brightness with my dedicated keyboard keys. Any idea? I have already an open question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220886/control-external-monitor-brightness).

Answer (score 1):

Copy bash script below to a file called `bright`

Then mark it executable with `chmod a+x bright`

## Bash Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MON="DP-1-1"    # Discover monitor name with: xrandr | grep " connected"
STEP=5          # Step Up/Down brightnes by: 5 = ".05", 10 = ".10", etc.

CurrBright=$( xrandr --verbose --current | grep ^"$MON" -A5 | tail -n1 )
CurrBright="${CurrBright##* }"  # Get brightness level with decimal place

Left=${CurrBright%%"."*}        # Extract left of decimal point
Right=${CurrBright#*"."}        # Extract right of decimal point

MathBright="0"
[[ "$Left" != 0 && "$STEP" -lt 10 ]] && STEP=10     # > 1.0, only .1 works
[[ "$Left" != 0 ]] && MathBright="$Left"00          # 1.0 becomes "100"
[[ "${#Right}" -eq 1 ]] && Right="$Right"0          # 0.5 becomes "50"
MathBright=$(( MathBright + Right ))

[[ "$1" == "Up" || "$1" == "+" ]] && MathBright=$(( MathBright + STEP ))
[[ "$1" == "Down" || "$1" == "-" ]] && MathBright=$(( MathBright - STEP ))
[[ "${MathBright:0:1}" == "-" ]] && MathBright=0    # Negative not allowed
[[ "$MathBright" -gt 999  ]] && MathBright=999      # Can't go over 9.99

if [[ "${#MathBright}" -eq 3 ]] ; then
    MathBright="$MathBright"000         # Pad with lots of zeros
    CurrBright="${MathBright:0:1}.${MathBright:1:2}"
else
    MathBright="$MathBright"000         # Pad with lots of zeros
    CurrBright=".${MathBright:0:2}"
fi

xrandr --output "$MON" --brightness "$CurrBright"   # Set new brightness

# Display current brightness
printf "Monitor $MON "
echo $( xrandr --verbose --current | grep ^"$MON" -A5 | tail -n1 )
```

- Change `MON="DP-1-1"` to your monitor name, ie `MON="eDP-1-1"`
- Change `STEP=5` to your step value, eg `STEP=2` is less noticeable

Call the script with:

- `bright Up` or `bright +` to increase brightness by step value
- `bright Down` or `bright -` to decrease brightness by step value
- `bright` (with no parameters) to get the current brightness level

Hopefully the bash / shell commands can easily be googled for education but if any questions don't hesitate to ask :)

8 minutes after posting answer it occurred to me I could have used `bc` for floating point math and saved ~10 lines of code and the a lot of time from the 1.5 hours to write it *shrugs*.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler bash...

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

# brightness [+-*/]f.f

set -f

MONITOR="$(xrandr --listactivemonitors | sed -n '/\*/p')"
MONITOR="${MONITOR##* }"

Brightness() { # current brightness value
   xrandr --verbose \
      | sed -nE "/^$MONITOR/ba;d
:a;s|[[:space:]]*Brightness:[[:space:]]*||p;tb;n;ba
:b;q"
}

Brightness_set() { # VALUE
   xrandr --output "$MONITOR" --brightness "$1"
}

[[ 0 -eq "$#" ]] \
   && printf '%s\n' "$MONITOR Brightness: $(Brightness)" \
   && exit

! [[ "$1" =~ ^([-+*/]?)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$ ]] \
   && >&2 printf '%s\n' "!!! USAGE: $(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}") ^([-+*/]?)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$" \
   && exit

if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ]]; then
   Brightness_set "$(bc <<< "$(Brightness)$1")"
else
   Brightness_set "$1"
fi
```

Keybind according to your wishes.