# The brightness control bar is not in the system settings of Ubuntu 14.04. How to get it there?

Tags: 14.04, brightness

The brightness control bar is not in the system settings of Ubuntu 14.04. How to get it there?

[image]

Currently I have lowered the brightness of my desktop due to [this wonderful solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/397104/43778), but I still want to know how to get it back in that window shown int the screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

First, open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Navigate to 11th line, there will be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line. Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` next to `quite splash` so the line would be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the file, then run `update-grub` command to apply change you have made:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, restart your system

Comment: You can't say "11th line" for example I've added 10 comments at the start of my grub

Comment: also, whether this will work or not depends on hardware