# Is there something similar to backlight `/sys/class/backlight/____/brightness` but for desktop computers?

Tags: python, 17.10, brightness, backlight

#### Background

I'm playing around with an experimental application for changing the brightness of computer screens. I started on my laptop computer and have been using `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to update the brightness, but on my desktop computer there's nothing in the `/sys/class/backlight` directory

#### Question

Where can I find something similar to the system file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` but for desktop computers with Ubuntu?

Or is there another interface for adjusting brightness on Ubuntu?

Grateful for help!

Comment: On a desktop computer, the brightness is handled be the monitor itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some interfaces exist, you can find them [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222506/brightness-adjustment-on-desktop-computer).

The DDC protocol (`apt-get install ddccontrol`) should do the trick