# Gnome brightness slider not working (Ubuntu 20:04.3 LTS)

Tags: brightness

The slider on top right for brightness does not work but volume and microphone sliders do work. As a temporary workaround, `xrandr` can set brightness and a shell script is about as convenient as using the slider. The script is below and should be used as `./brightness.sh 0.5` where 0.5 is the brightness you want to set it to. 1 is maximum and 0 is minimum.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Sets brightness on scale of 0 to 1
xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness $1
```

Edit: DP-0 is the screen, it is usually the default but not always. If this script does not work for you, check your screen id.

Comment: Looks like an answer to an unasked question.

Comment: Please write this as a question, then provide your answer as an answer to that question. This is perfectly fine on this site, and you may even accept your own answer. I would, however, recommend you to try the utility `light` that works on the hardware level (e.g. `light -U 1` to decrease brightness and `light +U 1` to increase), which can be bound to a shortcut key. `light` is in the repository of Ubuntu 21.04, else is available on github.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it is not a question. Also, see https://askubuntu.com/q/222506/124466, which has similar scripts.