Backlight/brightness not working in Ubuntu 23.10/24.04 on Dell 7700 AIO
Ubuntu 23.10/24.04
Dell Inspiron 7700 AIO
6.5.0-35-generic/6.8.0-31-generic
X11

Some recent 23.10/24.04 update has broken my system. The brightness slider is no longer visible. And the directory /sys/class/backlight/ is empty.
The backlight kernel driver dell-uart-backlight is not loaded on my 24.04 system. It's not even present on the 24.04 distribution.
If I boot to a Ubuntu 23.10.1 flash drive, it all works fine. So the problem has occurred since the 23.10.1 version.

[Update] Turns out that booting to the 23.10.1 flash drive only partially fixes the problem. The brightness slider appears, but it really doesn't update the screen brightness when moved. Booting to a 23.04 flash drive, and everything works as its supposed to.

[Update] Brightness control no longer working after update to Ubuntu 23.10 in computer Dell OptiPlex 7780 AIO
The command gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp returns:
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_5fpower_5fmanager_5ferror.Code1: No usable backlight could be found!

[Update] Adding the acpi_backlight=vendor kernel parameter in /etc/default/grub makes no difference.

[Update] I am able to set backlight brightness with the following xrandr command:
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.85

[Update] It seems that the dell-uart-backlight kernel driver is missing on my 24.04 system.
ls -alR /lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/ | grep dell
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 13689 Apr 26 02:32 dell-smm-hwmon.ko.zst
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 15 19:10 dell
/lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/dell:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18647 Apr 26 02:32 dell-laptop.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6158 Apr 26 02:32 dell-rbtn.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8431 Apr 26 02:32 dell_rbu.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13963 Apr 26 02:32 dell-smbios.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4432 Apr 26 02:32 dell-smo8800.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7762 Apr 26 02:32 dell-uart-backlight.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3799 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi-aio.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9209 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi-ddv.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4532 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi-descriptor.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11198 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3115 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi-led.ko.zst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 15 19:10 dell-wmi-sysman
/lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/dell/dell-wmi-sysman:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18312 Apr 26 02:32 dell-wmi-sysman.ko.zst

ls -alR /lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic/ | grep dell
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 15140 Apr 19 14:46 dell-smm-hwmon.ko.zst
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 25 10:15 dell
/lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/dell:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18629 Apr 19 14:46 dell-laptop.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6180 Apr 19 14:46 dell-rbtn.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8582 Apr 19 14:46 dell_rbu.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14726 Apr 19 14:46 dell-smbios.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4433 Apr 19 14:46 dell-smo8800.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3790 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi-aio.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9166 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi-ddv.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4492 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi-descriptor.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11306 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi.ko.zst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3108 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi-led.ko.zst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 25 10:15 dell-wmi-sysman
/lib/modules/6.8.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/dell/dell-wmi-sysman:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18307 Apr 19 14:46 dell-wmi-sysman.ko.zst

Removing acpi_backlight=vendor from /dev/default/grub makes no difference. However, adding acpi_backlight=video gives me the appropriate files in /sys/class/backlight, and I now get a brightness slider... although changing the slider doesn't actually change the brightness.

[Update] Submitted bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2067498


xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.85 Does that really change the brightness (i.e. backlight intensity)? It probably just changes the color contrast.

@ArchismanPanigrahi It seems to really change the brightness (however the xrandr command doesn't change the brightness slider). Please note the last update in my question. The dell_uart_backlight driver appears to be missing in 24.04, however I can get the acpi driver to load.

As a workaround you can use Brightness Controller (a gui for xrandr) https://askubuntu.com/a/397104/124466 until you find a fix

Perhaps you can create a Launchpad bug report about the missing kernel driver. Maybe Ubuntu developers turned off the option to compile the driver while building hte kernel.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for your input. In Synaptic, Brightness Controller wants to load a ton of qt5 dependencies... is that OK? Turns out the dell_uart_backlight is missing on the .iso image also. I read somewhere that there was a bug when probing dell_uart_backlight, so maybe they held it back pending a fix. I recently installed 24.04, but I swear that I thought that I saw that dell_uart_backlight was loaded. But without dell_uart_backlight, or a working acpi_video driver, I don't know how one could change the brightness. Please give me 10 seconds about doing a bug report. Thanks!

Brightness Controller wants to load a ton of qt5 dependencies... -- Yes, that is expected (I am a co-developer of it). Ubuntu does not ship with KDE programs by default,hence these qt5 dependencies are not present in default install. In Kubuntu you don't have to install so many dependencies.

@ArchismanPanigrahi See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2032174 for info about the dell_uart_backlight driver problem. They say it was fixed in 6.5.x kernels, but it may have resurfaced on 6.8.x kernels... hence the removal?

Workaround: Try using this tool to downgrade kernel to 6.1 (LTS support until 2027). https://github.com/bkw777/mainline I am sure by 2027 the brightness issue will be fixed in later kernel versions.

I suggest, please create a new Launchpad bug for kernel 6.8. The developers may be able to provide some feedback on why the issue resurfaced on kernel 6.8.

@ArchismanPanigrahi It turns out that dell_uart_backlight isn't in the 24.04 distribution. So backlight control will never work on a Dell. Also, there must be more wrong with the backlight code, as acpi_backlight=video shouldn't have been required to get the appropriate files into /sys/class/backlight. Kernels 6.1 and 6.2 don't fix the problem, as they don't ship with dell_uart_backlight, and there's no "extras" file to add it. Please give me 10 seconds of instruction on how to create a launchpad bug report.

First, create a launchpad account, and sign in. Then install the bug reporting tool with sudo apt install apport. Then, run the command ubuntu-bug linux to create a bug report against linux package. It will automatically generate relevant details in your computer and open a browser tab in Launchpad where you can fill in the details. Launchpad will automatically fill in relevant details about your system (ubuntu version, kernel version etc). Also, link this bug in your report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2032174

I have a Dell Latitude 5400 Chromebook (runs Mint 21.3). I will try Ubuntu 24.04 on that computer and let you know if I can control brightness.

@ArchismanPanigrahi https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2067498

In the bug report please also add that it worked perfectly in 23.04

@ArchismanPanigrahi Done. Thanks for your help!

Brightness does work on Lubuntu 24.04 on my Dell Latitude 5400 (chromebook edition). Perhaps it uses a different driver? I don't know how to check.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Show me what you see in /sys/class/backlight and grep -i backlight /etc/default/grub.

Sorry about the delay responding, and thanks for reminding. The content in /sys/class/backlight is intel_backlight, and there is no backlight in /etc/default/grub. Please note that it is a live session and not a full installation.

@ArchismanPanigrahi The reason that your brightness control works is because the OS detected the backlight, and put the Intel driver into /sys/class/backlight, and because your computer is not a DELL AIO, which uses a serial backlight connected via a UART.

I have a Dell Alienware m16 R2 Gaming Laptop (338-CNBV4) with Ubuntu 24.04 installed. F7 works fine to adjust the backlight brightness through 3 settings - off/low/bright.

@AntC This probably only applies to Dell AIO computers. Let's check... what do you see here... "ls /sys/class/backlight"?

nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight

@AntC You're system is working properly. None of this applies to you.

The dell-uart-backlight kernel driver that allows the setting of the backlight brightness is missing in 24.04. Even if this kernel driver was present, I suspect that there may still be problems with the brightness code in 23.10/24.04. This brightness problem probably effects all Dell AIO computers, because their backlight is driven via a UART.
Submitted bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2067498
Note: The xrandr command can be used to set the backlight brightness...
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.85

I had the same problem on 24.04 with my Dell Optiplex 5050.  Tried a few versions of Ubuntu with various kernels and still no joy.
Eventually I tried using ddcutil from this page as described here (see 1.3 External Monitors):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight
Once I verified this worked I added a DDC Backlight Gnome Extension which adds a separate brightness slider:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2944/ddc-brightness-control/
It's not a direct solution but it did solve the problem for me.

Excellent suggestion... however... the Dell Optiplex 5050 must not be an AIO machine... and your workaround is genius. However, on the Dell AIO's, their backlight is connected via a UART, and doesn't understand DDC, so this doesn't work. The DDC Backlight Gnome Extension shows as incompatible with 24.04 on my AIO.

oh I see.  that's a shame.
