# Does Brightness Control not work on desktop environments by design?

Tags: brightness, monitor

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a desktop and on a netbook. On the netbook, the brightness control works fine out of the box via GUI and hot keys. But on the desktop it does not. In the "Brightness and Locks" UI the brightness slider is missing, so it is only allows turning off of the display and locking.

So I searched about brightness control and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218953/can-i-control-brightness-on-second-monitor) which points to an external application for external displays.

Does this really mean that brightness control is not for desktop environments by design?

Is it because external monitors bring their own facilities for achieving this? But I am really tired of clicking through these on screen displays just to adjust brightness to daylight changes. I would prefer to use the keyboard as I do on the netbook.

Comment: also your question is a duplicate to the question you are linking to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218953/can-i-control-brightness-on-second-monitor

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve with this question. It seems rhetorical. I made a comment on the original question with a link to superuser where some options are given.

Comment: I want to clarify this point in an explicit question. When I was searching for brightness control I found a lot of questions & answers with references to `/sys/class/backlight` which does not work on desktops and external displays. Remember there is a system setting called "Brightness and Locks" which does not work on desktops for the first half of the title. Very likely I am not the only one searching for the error...

Comment: So... how is your question different wrt the one you're linking to?