# Is there a way to tie the brightness levels of each monitor together?

Tags: multiple-monitors, brightness

I have two monitors, one external, one part of my laptop. In order to set the brightness on my external monitor I have to use this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218953/can-i-control-brightness-on-second-monitor/457281?noredirect=1#comment1065953_457281).

But I really just want to be able to hit the button on my laptop to change brightness and have it affect both screens. How can I tie the brightness levels together?