# Display (Dual display) brightness control not working in 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, brightness, monitor, external-monitor

I upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 and display brightness controller is working the Primary display, but **it is not working Secondary display** (External display).

Comment: check this link [Can I control brightness on second monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218953/can-i-control-brightness-on-second-monitor?rq=1)

Comment: This way do not work correctly. The secondary monitor can't response.