# Brightness control doesn't work Acer Aspire 5738 13.04

Tags: 13.04, brightness, acer

I have tried many suggested solutions modifying, still nothing works.
Ubuntu 13.04.Acer Aspire 5738. 
Please help its very annoying and frustrating can't control a basic function.
Thanks

Comment: Although a hardware solution is preferable, I guess you could always use a software solution with the `xrandr` command http://askubuntu.com/questions/45153/is-there-an-alternative-to-redshift-and-f-lux-which-only-dims-the-screen/48952#48952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a definitive solution

Edit:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux i915.i915_enable_rc6=1"

in /etc/default/grub (and then updating with sudo update-grub)

thanks!

Source: [How do I adjust the screen brightness on an Acer Aspire One D270?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195011/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-brightness-on-an-acer-aspire-one-d270)